# Emulate Windows RDP Display behavior on macOS

Tags: display, remote-desktop, resolution

When I use RDP to connect from a Mac (MBP 13") -> Windows, I'm presented with a display at my native MBP resolution (2560x1600) and all windows are put onto that virtual desktop, even with two monitors connected to the PC. It basically pretends like my MBP is a remote screen and disconnects/locks the physical ones.

How can I emulate this behavior from macOS -> macOS?

It seems like it should be easier given I'm on the same OS but I haven't found any good way to do it. The best way I've found is using SwitchResX to set the display to 1280x800, then scaled to 2560x1600, and use a VNC client that supports zoom/scaling (Jump Desktop).

This isn't a great solution though because A) it's still not running at native res, B) requires me to manually switch the res with SwitchResX every time, and C) doesn't solve the multi-monitor problem. I'm able to set the display to 2560x1600 with SwitchResX, but not with HiDPI enabled making everything far too tiny.

Does anyone know of a better way to do this? I can't imagine it's too niche of a situation given  most Apple displays have non-standard resolutions, though I guess most people only use macOS on one screen.

Comment: What does this look like in practice? ***How can I emulate this behavior from macOS -> macOS?”*** basically I’m not at all clear what results you want Mac to Mac. Perhaps a drawing of what you want to see will clear this up if others struggle as well to see what you want. We have two to three displays on most of our work Mac and work PC and people remote back and forth all the time.

Comment: I don't believe this kind of functionality is possible. Afaik Windows RDP  creates a desktop environment on the client machine whereas macOS Screen Sharing.app uses the VNC protocol. You could think of it this way: Windows RDP sends instructions to the client about what elements it can draw (the client can set it's own window / desktop environment resolution) but the display is rendered client-side, macOS Screen Sharing.app sends a stream of images captured from whatever the host machine is displaying at the time and returns mouse + keyboard inputs to the host.